# How to Download and Share Certbot generated SSL?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certbot

I am using certbot generated SSL certificate on my server successfully. We have to integrate  a third party service which sends callback to our server and they asked us for our SSL certificate they need to install on their server, I am not sure what to share with them do I need to share live/cert.pem file generated by certbot or anything else.

Comment: Why do they need your SSL cert? LE is a trusted CA, it should be in their keystores, etc. already and their machines should trust a certificate signed by it....

Comment: @ivanivan how can I share with them if they still insist ? and which file should I share ?

Comment: Insist that they are wrong.  Your SSL cert will change every few weeks.  The only thing they can do with your cert is add it to their trusted certs list.  But they'll need to re-do it every time the cert changes.  On the other hand, I can think of more than a few things they can do WITH the cert, all of which include impersonating you/your site/your service ...  This may be an indicator of the quality and competency of the company you are dealing with ...